# figbib package: How to remove List of Figures from Table of Contents?

Tags: table-of-contents

I use the `figbib` package to include images in my document

(https://www-alg.ist.hokudai.ac.jp/~jan/figbib_doc.pdf) (On CTAN:
[figbib](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/figbib))

`\fbList{figures}` is used to generate the list of figures. Apparently when using this method to generate a list of figures it is included in the table of contents. I could use `\listoffigures` but then the sources of the images disappear for the list of figures .

How do I remove the `List of Figures` from my table of contents without removing the sources in list of figures?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! What document class are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Warning: The `figbib` package was last updated in `2004` and makes use of the outdated `epsfig` package.

It does support only `.eps` files and can't be used with `pdflatex`.

However, the sample file `figbib_sample.tex` and it's `.bib` file can be compiled still.

I used this sample file and modified it a little bit. The `\fbList` command is necessary to provide the references to the figures correctly -- however, it adds the `List of Figure` title to the `ToC`, which is not wanted by the O.P.

The main culprit for this is the code (from `figbib.sty`)

```
\@ifundefined{chapter}
  {\def\figbib@section{%
     \section*{\figbibListHeader}%
     \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\figbibListHeader}}}%
  {\def\figbib@section{%
     \chapter*{\figbibListHeader}%
     \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\figbibListHeader}}}
```

I changed this in the driver file and added a `\iffigbibintoc` switch which defaults to `false` here -- if the entry is requested, say `\figbibintoctrue` (before \fbList` is used).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[center,xpart]{figbib}


\newif\iffigbibintoc

\makeatletter

\@ifundefined{chapter}
  {\def\figbib@section{%
     \section*{\figbibListHeader}%
     \iffigbibintoc
     \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\figbibListHeader}%
     \fi
   }}%
  {\def\figbib@section{%
     \chapter*{\figbibListHeader}%
     \iffigbibintoc
     \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\figbibListHeader}%
     \fi
   }}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\section*{The Text}

In the first paragraph, we introduce the smiley in
\fbref{smiley1}.

\fbEpsfig{smiley1}{2cm}{b!} % a simple figure definition

In the second paragraph, nothing happens.

\begin{fbFloat}[b!] % a more complex figure definition
\begin{fbMinipage}{6cm}
\fbEps{smiley2}{2cm}
\end{fbMinipage}
\fbhspace{3cm}
\fbEpsM{smiley3}{2cm}
\end{fbFloat}

\section*{The Figures}
\fbTheFigs

\fbList{figbib_sample}

\end{document}
```

Here is the unchanged `figbib_sample.bib` (as provided by the package author)

```
@fig{smiley1,
  main = {This is a smiley},
  add = {The additional description is meaningless},
  caption = {Smiley},
  file = {smiley}
}

@fig{smiley2,
  main = {Here is the smiley again},
  file = {smiley}
}

@fig{smiley3,
  main = {Yet another smiley},
  file = {smiley},
  source = {(top secret)}
}
```

I've omitted a screenshot -- it will show an empty `ToC` ;-)

**Compilation**

Use following sequence

1. latex foo
2. bibtex foo.figbib % Note the extension
3. latex foo
4. latex foo
5. latex foo

i.e. up to four compilations are necessary.